# Chrome Extension, Append Element & Re-Append Across Page Changes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that, when its button is clicked, appends an element to the current page. However, I want to keep that element across pages; i.e., if the user clicks on a link, the new page loads, and then the element is appended.

I tried using `window.onhashchange` to detect page changes, check if the element was appended, and if not, append it, but that didn't seem to have any affect at all. Any tips on how to do this, or if it's possible? (preferably in javascript, no jquery)

Answer (score 1):

some general description how would I do it, would be:
-when user clicks the button, append element and <s>send msg to background to</s> store that tab (ID)
-add listeners chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener & onUpdated  (in bg script)
-test newly created and updated tabs  against your stored
-if newly created/updated tab is child of your stored tab (tabs), inject script for element appending or send msg to content script to append element

sample for BG script to start with:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
    console.log('tab id is'+tab.id);
    console.log('opener is'+tab.openerTabId);
});
```

cople of things to be careful:
-openerTabId is undefined if link is dragged (extension for dragging links)
-those events are fired multiple times, so if you are sending msg  to content script to append your element (or injecting), check it first
something like

```
if (yourElement) return;
else //append element
```

maybe there are better/simpler ways to achieve what you want... can't think of it right now

**EDIT:**
you actually don't need initial messaging when button is clicked, because listener for that button is already in bg script, and the whole process is very simple.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I hope there's an easier way, but if not, I'll be sure to mark your answer as accepted!